# UILabel and Zapinfo

Tags: ios

Here is very simple code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapinfo" size:20];
label.text = @"f";
```

Most of the fonts are rendered correctly, except very specific ones like Zapinfo. For example, when a letter 'f' is drawn just a center of this symbol is shown, left and right curls are missed. Moreover, this effect can be easy repeated in Interface Builder. Is this bug or feature? What should I do to show entire, non-cutted letters?

Comment: I'm guessing the `UILabel` height is too small to fit the font size. You can try bij turn of the clipping: `label.clipsToBounds = NO;` This will not fix the issue but will at least draw the font outside of the labels bounds.

Comment: use this...it will shows right left curls.

label.text = @"'f'";

Comment: The height of UILabel is big enough - I can set it to 300, issue will be the same. ClipToBounds solves the problem by a half - UILabel should be placed at some unknown coordinate X. Is there some way to find this X? Ideally, is there some way to save a text as an image with minimal size? I was trying CTLine, CTFrame, NSAttributedString, but no success. They are all fail with Zapinfo font.